# Issue with using pandas fillna()

Tags: python, dataframe, fillna

I have a DF with cols 'category' and 'fund_size', with fund_size with missing values. Unique values = ['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'].

What I am trying to do is - for all unique values is category, get the mode value of fund_size and replace the na values with Mode.

```
for cat in not_bonds['category'].unique():
   new_df= not_bonds.loc[mf["category"] == cat]
   max_val = new_df['fund_size'].mode().tolist()

   if len(max_val) >= 1:
       #print(max_val[0])

       not_bonds.loc[not_bonds['category'] == cat, fund_size'].fillna(max_val[0], inplace=True)
       #print(cat, max_val[0])
    else:
        continue
```

The problem is the values are still blanks in fund_size.

at the same time, if I do this manually, i get the values updated -

```
val = not_bonds.loc[not_bonds['category'] == 'Bear Market', 'fund_size'].mode().tolist()[0]
```

val

not_bonds.loc[not_bonds['category'] == 'Bear Market', 'fund_size'].fillna(val, inplace=True)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you've removed the indentation of your code in the snippet above. Could you perhaps copy/paste it exactly as you are using it? One possibility is that the if/else statement isn't within the for loop.

Comment: indentation corrected, but that was only a cop paste to stack exchange, else the error would have been differnet.

Comment: hmm - in the second line is there a possible issue with `mf["category"]`? Is `mf` a copy of the same data frame?

Comment: Thanks, but even with that correction from mf to 'non_bonds', nothing change. mf is just the main data frame